# Django Form Is None

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, jinja2

Im on investigation Django framework and now trying to create custom procedure of resetting password.

I use this URL path

```
path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>', 
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='user_account/reset_password/password_reset_confirm.html',
            success_url='/account/password_reset_complete/'),
        name="password_reset_confirm"),
```

In template i use crispy form

```
<form class="login-form p-4 rounded" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
  <h1 class="h4 mb-4 font-weight-bold">Change your password</h1>
      <p>Use the form below to change your password.</p>

       {{ form|crispy }}

 <button type="submit" value="Change">
    Submit
 </button>
</form>
```

So now this form do not showing in template, and if if type {{ form }} instead of {{ form.as_p }} or crispy form, that showing me **None** in form place.

Comment: can you share your url paths (all of the if you can). It is possible that another url path is being matched instead of the one you sent above. (You can also try changing the path to some random one and test it again)